# skimage.transform.rescale adds an extra dimension to input image

Tags: python, image-processing, computer-vision, scikit-image, rescale

When using `skimage.transform.rescale()` I get an output image array of which has 3 dimensions when my input image is just 2 dimensions.

```
from skimage import io, color, transform

image = io.imread(r'C:\Users\ParthD\PycharmProjects\pythonProject\test_images\6.png')
image_bw = color.rgb2gray(color.rgba2rgb(image))
image_rescaled = transform.rescale(image, scale=0.5, anti_aliasing=True)

print(image_bw.shape)
print(image_rescaled.shape)
```

To this I get the output as:

```
(397, 602)
(198, 301, 2)
```

Where is that additional dimension with value 2 is getting added up, I'm not sure. I checked with the rescale function documentation but there is no parameter which contributes to this extra dimension.

Comment: You are rescaling `image`, not `image_bw`.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

So the problem is that the *channel* dimension is interpreted as a spatial dimension.

You should pass `transform.rescale` the `multichannel=True` flag so it won't affect the channels:

```
image_rescaled = transform.rescale(image, scale=0.5, anti_aliasing=True, multichannel=True)
```

- Example:

  ```
  q = np.zeros((397, 602, 3))
  x1 = transform.rescale(q, scale=0.5, anti_aliasing=True)
  x2 = transform.rescale(q, scale=0.5, anti_aliasing=True, multichannel=True)
  x1.shape  # (198, 301, 2)
  x2.shape  # (198, 301, 3)
  ```

So `transform.rescale` treats your array as a 3D image of shape (397, 602, 3), which goes down to (198, 301, 2), interpolating along with the channel as well, as if they were another spatial dimension.

In case your image is gray image, with no channel dimension, you do not need to pass the `multichannel=True` flag. This will cause the last axis to be treated as channel and you get undesired output.

- Example:

  ```
  q1 = np.zeros((397, 602))
  x3 = transform.rescale(q1, scale=0.5, anti_aliasing=True, multichannel=True)
  x4 = transform.rescale(q1, scale=0.5, anti_aliasing=True)
  x3.shape  # (198, 602)
  x4.shape  # (198, 301)
  ```

You can refer to the [docs](https://scikit-image.org/docs/stable/api/skimage.transform.html#skimage.transform.rescale)